# Widget Not Updating Views

Tags: java, android, android-intent, widget, textview

So basically my Widget updates, according to my LogCat, and the TextView in my Widget's Layout is not. It updates when it first starts, but what I am trying to do is update it artificially using an intent after a BrocastReceiver. The intent works fine, the onUpdate runs after the onReceive, but the text is not updated. I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that a different context, AppWidgetManager, or appWidgetIds are being used.

Here are my methods:

```
String sent = "0";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null && action.equals("27")){
        Log.i("Updating", "UPDATING WIDGET");
        sent = intent.getStringExtra("Sent");
        onUpdate(context,AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context),
                new int[]{0});
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds){
    Log.i("Widget","onUpdate");
    String begin = "Sent ";
    String end = " Texts Since Last Visit";
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N; i++){
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,History.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.LLwidget, pi);
        Log.i("Widget","Sent: " + sent);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.SentTextView, begin + sent + end);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
    </receiver>
```

widget_info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:updatePeriodMillis="30000" 
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout" 
  android:minHeight="72dip" 
  android:minWidth="146dip">

</appwidget-provider>
```

I think that is all the necessary information considering I know for sure that the intent works and the onUpdate runs.

Hopefully someone can help me because this is my first attempt at a widget and my brain is a little frazzled because of lack of sleep over this.
Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in `0` as an app widget ID. More than likely, that is not a valid app widget ID. Either use an appropriate app widget ID (e.g., one you put in an extra of the `Intent` you attach to the click event) or use the version of `updateAppWidget()` that does not take an app widget ID.

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured but did not know a method of fixing this. Hopefully with this information I can come to a conclusion

Comment: Fixed the problem by getting the AppWidgetIds using a componentname and the instance of AppWidgetManager 
`provider = new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);`

`AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(provider);`